# accessing block type in the theme_preprocess_node()

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a block which include a view which is based on node.tpl.php, and I want to change the mark up in the node.tpl.php file just for a specified block.

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $block = unknown_way_to_get_it();
  if ($block->region == "product_stream") {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__productstream';
  }
}
```

How do I get a block from the preprocess function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get access to a block object from a node preprocess hook; the context simply isn't passed down the chain.

As you're using a view, though, you can get hold of the View object, and test the name/display id. The basic idea would be:

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['view'])) {
    if ($variables['view']->name == 'some_view' && $variables['view']-> current_display == 'block_1') {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__productstream';
    }
  }
}
```